# Hide unchecked radio buttons only with CSS

Tags: html, css

So I came across this project with a particularity that I cannot use javascript. The point is to hide any content related with radio buttons that are not checked. All the content is displayed once the page load but after one radio button content is selected I have to make all the other radio buttons disappear.

This is my markup:

```html
       <label>
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" />
                <div class="radio-sample">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
                    <div class="con">
                        <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
                            "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</p>
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">1Primary</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" />
                <div class="radio-sample">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
                    <div class="con">
                        <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
                            "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</p>
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">2Primary</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3" />
                <div class="radio-sample">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
                    <div class="con">
                        <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
                            "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</p>
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">2Primary</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
```

Comment: This is not possible using only CSS.

Comment: that works only for 2 radio buttons content but not for 3 or more, which i didnt specify but is a requirement, let me update the code

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:not(:checked)` to invert the checked selector.

Here is an example

```css
input[type=radio]:not(:checked)~.radio-sample {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" />
  <div class="radio-sample">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="con">
      <p>Number 1</p>
      <button>Primary button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" />
  <div class="radio-sample">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="con">
      <p>Number 2</p>
      <button>Primary button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3" />
  <div class="radio-sample">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="con">
      <p>Number 3</p>
      <button>Primary button 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: this could work, but how to do I show all the radio buttons when the page loads? they are hidden by default and should be visible

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:checked` pseudo-class with the `~` (sibling) selector:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ div.radio-sample {
    display: none;
}
```

However, because the inputs will all initially be unchecked then all of the content will be hidden. The only solution is to set the HTML so all that the radio buttons are all initially checked:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" />
```

...then after the user selects one the others will be unchecked and their content hidden.

Comment: that works only for 2 radio buttons content but not for 3 or more, which i didnt specify but is a requirement, let me update the code